# How to Integrate Apache NiFi and Azure Active Directory for user authentication?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, apache-nifi

I am working on secure NiFi to authenticate users through Azure Active Directory. How can I do that? I found resources using LDAP. But we don't have any Local Active Directory or LDAP other than Azure AD. We are using Tableau where Tableau users are authenticated through Azure Active Directory. It gets synchronized once in a day with tableau server's user list. Now my plan is to do the same user authentication for NiFi users with Azure AD. How can I do that? Any guidelines and help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It appears Azure Active Directory supports OpenID Connect authentication, which Apache NiFi supports. You can read about that on [Microsoft's site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/index), and there are [definitions for each property for configuring OpenID Connect](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/administration-guide.html#openid_connect) in NiFi in the Administrator's Guide.

In general, you will need to:

1. Configure TLS for NiFi (no authentication mechanisms are enabled when TLS is off)
2. Configure the OpenID Connect endpoint and client ID/secret in `nifi.properties`
3. Configure users & groups

There are [step-by-step instructions for configuring OpenID Connect & NiFi](https://bryanbende.com/development/2017/10/03/apache-nifi-openid-connect) on Bryan Bende's blog.

*Note:* I understand avoiding "doc link only" answers, but that's the question and reposting all the steps is overkill.

Comment: @ Andy, Thanks for the resource. I followed the steps and it worked with Gmail account. But when I started with Azure AD , it first went to microsfot page and asking for username/password, after that Nifi UI comes up with error "Unable to exchange authorization for ID token: Unable to extract email from the UserInfo token." Any help how can i resolve this? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I have not used the Azure AD before. If it follows the standard OIDC protocol, it should work. You can enable lower level debugging on NiFi to further examine the interaction between the authorizer and Azure AD.

Comment: @MarshalTito were you able to figure it out? I'm trying to do exactly this as well.

Comment: @rexbelia You can follow the above-mentioned link along with this one. hope it will work for you. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-4698